# Partition table using non-unique rows in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to partition a MySQL table using the date as the partition column (basically trying to partition it so that 30 days worth of data is stored and the rest gets auto-purged). However, the compiler gives me the error "A Primary Key must include all columns in the table's partitioning function" when I try to Partition by Range using the date column. However, I can't make the date column the primary key because a lot of the dates happen to be the same, so they won't be unique anymore. Is there anyway to get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you want to drop the primary key or add it as a primary key. No lee way in between